# Why is augmenting path calculation O(m)

Tags: complexity-theory

I'm trying to learn augmenting paths and I got confused. I've found some other source that has the same setup that my slides have, therefore I will refer to that.

It is said that

> Each augmenting path computation can be easily done in O(m) time.

in [these lecture notes](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.854/16/Notes/n8-flow_computation.html) within a graph of m edges. I could not understand how it is O(m). Isn't trying to find an augmenting path that has capacity from source to the target an exhaustive process? Maybe I misunderstand what they mean as augmenting path computation but even if that is the case, the clarification of that would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As given in your lecture notes, and an *augmenting path* is an s-t path in the residual graph such that all edges on the path have a positive residual capacity.

There could be many augmenting paths in the graph. But you just need to find one such path. Therefore, you can apply **DFS** or **BFS** which takes $O(m)$ time to find one such path from $s$ to $t$.

Comment: I accepted the answer but after giving some thought, isn't complexity of DFS is $O(m+n)$? What do I miss?

Comment: @iRestMyCaseYourHonor Yes, you are right. In general, we do say DFS takes $O(m+n)$ time. But for a connected graph $m> n$. In that case, it is equivalent to say $O(m+n)$ or $O(m)$.

Comment: @iRestMyCaseYourHonor Since here you are only performing DFS from $s$, the algorithm only traverses the vertices that are connected to $s$. This means vertices traversed are at most $m$. Therefore, saying $O(m)$ is correct. If there are isolated vertices, the algorithm is not traversing them.

Comment: Hmm.. thanks! There might be cases where even though we start from node s, the target we look for can be in a different isolated group than s and we might still want to traverse those sets. Then our complexity would be $O(m+n)$ right? However in augmenting path setting, it is not needed so it is safe to say $O(m)$ right?

Comment: @iRestMyCaseYourHonor Yes, you are right. In augmenting path setting, if you did not find $t$ while doing DFS from $s$, you can simply exit and declare path not found. Therefore, you do not need to visit other isolated groups.